# SSRS syntax converted from visual basic syntax

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

How would the following be writting in SSRS syntax?

```
If (( Fields!Name.Value = "Completed") or ( Fields!Name.Value = "Approved") or ( Fields!Name.Value = "Denied") or ( Fields!Name.Value = "Cancelled")) Then
     Fields!Name.Value =  Fields!Name.Value
ELSE
     Fields!Name.Value = "Other"
END IF
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to populate a tablix cell with the values specified, and this is your dataset:

[image: Dataset]

The expression:

```
=IIF((Fields!Name.Value = "Completed") OR (Fields!Name.Value = "Approved") OR    
     (Fields!Name.Value = "Denied") OR (Fields!Name.Value = "Cancelled"),
     Fields!Name.Value, "Other")
```

Produces this result:

[image: Result]